# Is there a way to cut off parts of an instantiated text?

Tags: c#

I have a school project with my classmates making a VR game about a post-office where you simply stack packages and send them off to the public. In our menu we have stamps that correspond to different difficulties which set the level when you stamp on a certain box. I have coded so whenever you use a stamp it instantiates a text with the corresponding difficulty. Code below:

```
public class Stampspawner : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject stampDifficultyPrefab;
    public float timer;
    private string stampDifficulty;
    void Update()
    {
        timer -= Time.deltaTime;

    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (timer <= 0)
        {
            if (gameObject.name == "StampLower_StampLower")
            {
                stampDifficulty = "LÄTT";
            }

            else if (gameObject.name == "stamplower1_stamplower1")
            {
                stampDifficulty = "LAGOM";
            }

            else if (gameObject.name == "Teeth_Teeth")
            {
                stampDifficulty = "SVÅR";
            }

            stampDifficultyPrefab.GetComponent<TextMesh>().text = 
            stampDifficulty; 
            GameObject go = Instantiate(stampDifficultyPrefab, 
            transform.position, 
            Quaternion.identity, other.transform);

            if (gameObject.name == "Teeth_Teeth") 
            {
                go.transform.rotation = gameObject.transform.rotation * 
                Quaternion.Euler(90, 180, 270);
            }
            else if (gameObject.name == "StampLower_StampLower")
            {
                go.transform.rotation = gameObject.transform.rotation * 
                Quaternion.Euler(90, 270, 270);
            }
            else
            {
                go.transform.rotation = gameObject.transform.rotation * 
                Quaternion.Euler(90, 90, 270);
            }

            timer = 2f;
        }   
    }
}
```

On this picture I have used my stamp to stamp the text on the edge of a table and thus the text spawns half inside and half outside of the table.

[image: Picture of how the text goes outside the table]

Comment: Can you clarify a bit more exactly what you mean by "is there a way to cut off parts of an instantiated text"? Are you trying to reuse a portion of those gameObject.name strings or something else?

Comment: It think you want to create a class that inherits the TextBox where you can add additional properties like difficulty.  If you have a picture then inherit the PictureBox.

Comment: @G_P I added a picture now that hopefully can show what I meant.